# Passing Makefile pattern in multiple targets to dependency

Tags: makefile

I'm trying to match a dependency based on the instantiated target in a Makefile.

I would expect this code to work, but it doesn't.

```
a b: $@.test

*.test:
  echo $@
```

I would like `make a` to output `a.test`.

Additionally, how can I access the `*` part and simply output `a`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would you expect that to work?

First, you can't use `$@` in a prerequisite list like `a b: $@.test`; automatic variables are [only defined inside recipes](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html), not in prerequisite lists.  So it's empty.

Second, when make parses your makefile it will expand `*.test` by looking for all the files on the disk that match that pattern and presumably there aren't any (since you haven't built them yet) so this will expand to the empty string.

Basically your makefile is the same as if you'd written:

```
a b: .test

:
        echo $@
```

If you want `make a` to output `a.test` you can do it using [static-pattern rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Static-Usage.html) like this:

```
a b : % : %.test

%.test:
        echo $@
```

If you want just the part that matches the pattern [use `$*`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html) instead of `$@`.